# boolean equation to truth table

Tags: functions

My question is to make a truth table from a given boolean equation.
The boolean equation is $M =  A'B’C +  A’BC’  +  ABC’ +  ABC$

I get the following results but I think I did something wrong. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

The output of the truth table was: $00110101$

Comment: What is the output of a truth table?

Comment: the output is 00110101....this website wont let me post the whole table so i just posted the output column

Comment: A truth table is generally considered to be an array with $2^n$ rows and $n+1$ columns. The first $n$ columns ($n=3$ here) have entries giving the values taken on by the $n$ variables, the last column has the corresponding value of the function $M$.  The website _does_ allow you to post the whole table, but you will need to use the built-in MathJax functionality.

Comment: im just trying to figure out if my output column is correct or not because i dont think so but i cant figure it out

Comment: Ah, so the "output of the truth table" is the column giving the truth values of the expression? In that case, how did you sort the rows? Is it "FFF,FFT,FTF,…" or "FFF,TFF,FTF,…"?

Comment: the order goes first column: 00001111, second column: 00110011, third column: 01010101

Answer (score 1):

You indeed did something wrong.

If you look at the term $M=A′B′C+A′BC′+ABC′+ABC$, then $M$ is $1$ iff any of the terms is $1$. Each term is true iff every of its factor is $1$. And $A'$ is $1$ if $A$ is $0$.

Let's look at a smaller expression (which also saves me typing):
$X = A'B' + A'B + AB$

Let's first consider the first term, $A'B'$. This is $1$ if both $A'$ and $B'$ are $1$. But $A'=1$ if $A=0$, and $B'=1$ if $B=0$. So the only case when $A'B'$ is $1$ is when $A=B=0$.

Now let's look at the second term, $A'B$. Again, this is $1$ iff $A'=B=1$. But $A'=1$ iff $A=0$. Therefore the only way $A'B$ is $1$ is iff $A=0$ and $B=1$.

You might see a pattern now: In each term, all the primed factors have to be $0$ and all non-primed $1$. So let's verify it at the third term: $AB$. Both are unprimed, so both have to be $1$. And indeed, that's the case.

Now $X$ becomes $1$ if *any* of the terms is $1$.  Therefore for $X$ we get the truth table:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
A & B & \text{matching term} & X\\
\hline
0 & 0 & A'B' & 1\\
0 & 1 & A'B & 1\\
1 & 0 & \text{---} & 0\\
1 & 1 & AB & 1
\end{array}$$
As you see, $X=1$ if there's a matching term in $X$, and $X=0$ otherwise.

Remark: This can also done in reverse. Because your truth table has an entry $1$ in the rows $010$, $011$, $101$ and $111$, your truth table would be correct for the expression $Y=A'BC'+A'BC+AB'C+ABC$.

With this information, you should now be able to get the correct truth table also for $M$.